# Adding to a Multidimensional Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, addition

I have a multidimensional array that I am creating from a JSON Ajax call to my DB.

With in my Web App, I am trying to dynamically add a new row to the array using javascript along the lines of:

```js
list[new_row_id].item_id = new_value ;
list[new_id].item_title = new_title  ;
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You can access the second dimension using brackets too. So it would be something like ```list[d1][d2] = value```

Comment: Did you make `list[new_row_id]` an object before trying to set `.item_id = new value` on it? What led you to believe your code didn't work? For example, did you get an error message? If so, what? Please [edit] the post to show a minimal, runnable, complete chunk of your relevant code as a [mcve]. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an element to the end of an array is done with the `push`-function:

```
array.push({"item_id": 10101, "item_title": "new title"});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant "new_id" and "new_row_id" to be the same and it differs from an index starting from 0, because the keys are individual database keys, then you can solve it that way:

```
var any_db_id = 33;
var new_title = 'new title';
list[any_db_id] = {
    item_id: any_db_id,
    title: new_title
}
```

That will result in a JSON looking like that:

```
{
    1: {
        item_id: 1,
        title: 'Entry coming from database 1'
    },
    5: {
        item_id: 5,
        title: 'Entry coming from database 2'
    },
    33: {
        item_id: 33,
        title: 'new title'
    }
}
```

If the new_id and new_row_id are still same but it is actually just an index (each item has 0, 1, 2 and so on as key), then you should use the solution of Virendra Katariya.